# Get Axios with basic Auth and Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

i need your help:
I am trying to perform a get to an API that requires a username and password.
I implemented it as follows:

```
  axios.get('https://example.net/rest/executions/1266026155/execution-log', {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    },{
      auth: {
        username: "username12345",
        password: "12345678"
    }}).then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("All OK")
    }
})
```

but the message in the browser is:

xhr.js:177 GET https://example.net/rest/executions/1266026155/execution-log net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

in Postman my try obtained one results satisfatorys.
[image]
[image]

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I Solved this problem in the following way:

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false });
    const session_url = `/rest/executions/1266026155/execution-log`
    var username = 'myUserName'
    var password = 'myPass'
      
    axios.get(session_url, {
      withCredentials: true,
      auth: {
        username: username,
        password: password
      },
        httpsAgent: httpsAgent,
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }).then( response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log("Success")
          }
      }
```

but first I had to configure the proxy:
We have two options:
a) Add parameter in package.json

```
"proxy": 'https://myProxy.com/3000'
```

b) Config proxy with http-proxy-middleware:

```
npm install --save-dev http-proxy-middleware
```

then create archive: setupProxy.js
in the content:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/oo/rest/executions',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'https://myProxy.com/3000',
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

then we run proyect with:

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to send some data on the server, you should use POST method, as GET doesn't have any **body** with **data**. And dont't forget to import

```js
axios.post('https://example.net/rest/executions/1266026155/execution-log', {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  },{
    body: {
      username: "username12345",
      password: "12345678"
  }}).then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log("All OK")
  }
})
```

Comment: I want to read data from the API, it requires username and password. In PostMan I get everything correctly with Get, but not with axios.